# How to write a simple program $polyapp(x,y,n)$ that finds the coefficient vector $\mathbf{c}$ for a polynomial interpolant

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, solution-verification, interpolation

I am self-learning some numerical algorithms from the book `Numerical methods in Scientific computing` by Dahlquist/Bjorck. Problem 4.1.2 asks to write a program that finds the coefficient vector $\mathbf{c}$ for a polynomial interpolant. I'd like someone to help verify my solution, as my interpolation polynomial does not properly fit the data.

> **Question.** (a) Write a program $c = polyapp(x,y,n)$ that finds the coefficient vector $c$ for a polynomial in $p \in \mathcal{P}_n$, in a shifted power basis, such that $y_i \approx p(x_i)$ for $i=1:m,m \ge n$, in the least squares sense, or study a program that does almost this.

> (b) The following data show the development of the Swedish Gross Domestic Product (GDP), quoted from a table made by a group associated with the Swedish Employer's confederation. (The data are expressed in prices of 1985 and scaled so that the value for 1950 is 100.

```
x = np.array([1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990])
y = np.array([100.0, 117.7,139.3,179.3,219.3,249.1,267.5,291.5,326.4])
```

> For the upper pairs of the data, compute and plot $p(x)$, $x \in [1950,2000]$. Mark the given data points. Do this for $m=9$ and for say $n=9$ and then for $n=8:-2:2$. Store the results so that comparisons can be made afterwards.

**My Attempt.**

Solution. The shifted power basis for $\mathcal{P}_n$ is given by,

$$
\begin{align*}
p_1(x) &= 1\\
p_2(x) &= (x - d)\\
p_3(x) &= (x - d)^2\\
\vdots\\
p_n(x) &= (x - d)^n
\end{align*}
$$

We have $m > n$ data points. The interpolation problem is, $p(x_i) = f(x_i)$ for $i=1:m$. In matrix form, $M_n(\mathbf{p}) \mathbf{c} = f$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1(x_1) & p_2(x_1) & \ldots & p_n(x_1) \\
p_1(x_2) & p_2(x_2) & \ldots & p_n(x_2) \\
p_1(x_3) & p_2(x_3) & \ldots & p_n(x_3) \\
\vdots\\
p_1(x_m) & p_2(x_1) & \ldots & p_n(x_m)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3 \\
\vdots\\
c_n
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
f(x_1)\\
f(x_2)\\
f(x_3)\\
\vdots\\
f(x_m)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We are interested to find the coefficient vector $\mathbf{c}$ such that the sum of the squared residuals

$$
S(\mathbf{c}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_j p_j(x_i) - f(x_i) \right]^2
$$

is minimized. The partial derivative with respect to $c_k$ is,

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial S(\mathbf{c})}{\partial c_k} &= 2\sum_{i=1}^{m}p_k(x_i)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_j p_j(x_i)-f(x_i)\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{i=1}^{m}p_k(x_i) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j p_j(x_i)\right) -2 \sum_{i=1}^{m}p_k(x_i)f(x_i)
\end{align*}
$$

The function is minimized at the critical point where the gradient is zero.

My `polyapp(x,y,n)` routine is as follows.

````
def polyapp(x,y,n):
    m = len(x) # No of data points
    a = min(x) # Determine the interval [a,b]
    b = max(x)
    d = (a + b)/2 
    
    # We assume a shifted power basis for a polynomial p in P_n.
    def p(x,k):
        return (x - d)**k
    
    # We find the coefficient vector c for a polynomial p in P_n, such that 
    # y_i = p(x_i) in a least squares sense. The coefficient vector is given by the solution of a square linear
    # algebraic system.
    
    A = np.zeros((n,n))
    
    # The term multiplying c_j in the k'th equation is sum_{i=1}^m p_k(x_i) p_j(x_i)
    
    for k in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            for i in range(0,m):
                A[k,j] = A[k,j] + p(x[i],k) * p(x[i],j)
                
    
    # Construct the right hand side vector 
    b = np.zeros(m)
    
    for k in range(0,n):
        for i in range(0,m):
            b[k] = b[k] + y[i]*p(x[i],k)
        b[k] = b[k] * n
            
    c = linalg.solve(A,b)
    return A,c

def polyval(x,c,d,n):
    y = 0
    for j in range(0,n):
        y = y + c[j]*((x - d)**j)
    return y
```
````

Comment: I had an erroneous $n$ in the term $n \sum_{i=1}^{m}p_k(x_i)f(x_i)$.The right hand side vectors are given by $\sum_{i=1}^{m}p_k(x_i)f(x_i)$. That's one of the errors.

Comment: If you use `linalg.solve` you can also use `linalg.qr` to get $QR=M$, then solve $Rc=Q^Tf$. This gives the same solution with more numerical stability

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thanks for that suggestion. Also, I've made some indexing error in my algorithm, it thinks that $(1955,100.0),(1960,117.7),\ldots$ are the data points. But, I can't seem to spot what's wrong with the code.

Comment: related? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254996/implementing-basic-polynomial-interpolation